# How to activate Spring Security in a webflux war application

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

How to activate a `webflux` security in a **war packaging** application. I am using the Spring 5 built-in `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherHandlerInitializer`, but it does not work.

```
public class AppIntializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherHandlerInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
            WebConfig.class,
            SecurityConfig.class
        };
    }
}
```

But it seems the Spring Security WebFilter is not enabled. Spring Security 5 does not include a Reactor specific `WebApplicationInitializer` to activate Spring security filter chain.

Stack: Spring Security 5.0.0.M4

Source codes: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/war/src/main/java/com/example/demo/AppIntializer.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherHandlerInitializer`. However, there is a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16144) in `AbstractDispatcherHandlerInitializer`. You can work around the problem using:

```java
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherHandlerInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
            WebConfig.class,
            SecurityConfig.class
        };
    }

    protected void registerDispatcherHandler(ServletContext servletContext) {
        String servletName = getServletName();
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = createApplicationContext();

        refreshApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        registerCloseListener(servletContext, applicationContext);

        HttpHandler httpHandler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(applicationContext)
            .build();
        ServletHttpHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new ServletHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet(servletName, handlerAdapter);

        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping(getServletMapping());
        registration.setAsyncSupported(true);

        customizeRegistration(registration);
    }
}
```

In Spring 5.0.2.RELEASE+ (scheduled for release Nov 15, 2017) you can extend `AbstractReactiveWebInitializer` instead.

```java
public class AppIntializer extends AbstractReactiveWebInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
            WebConfig.class,
            SecurityConfig.class
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Unluckily, `AbstractReactiveWebInitializer` did not work in my sample. I have updated it to Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7(which contains Spring 5.0.2.RELEASE), it seems  `AbstractReactiveWebInitializer`  did not refresh the `applicationContext`, I overrode `createApplicationContext` method to overcome this barrier, see [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/war/src/main/java/com/example/demo/AppIntializer.java#L51-L57), the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(configClasses)` includes a **refresh** action, but the default constructor does not.