# Spring WebFlux 5.0.RELEASE and Spring Security 5.0.M5

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to build a web service using WebFlux. When I tried to configure Spring Security with Spring WebFlux, the requests are not intercepted by Spring Security. My Spring Security config is:

```
@EnableWebFlux
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public MapUserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository() {
        UserDetails cust =
           User.withUsername("user1").password("password") 
            .roles("USER").build();
        UserDetails admin = 
          User.withUsername("admin1").password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN").build();
        return new MapUserDetailsRepository(cust, admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(
        HttpSecurity httpSecurity) {
    return httpSecurity.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().
             authenticated().and().build();
}
```

}

Comment: How are you specifying the security annotations? Are you doing it on controllers or are you using method level security on handlers?

Comment: I'm not using @Secured annotation because it won't work.

Comment: I saw someone facing the similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325632/how-to-activate-spring-security-in-a-webflux-war-application

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use method security. You need to add `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity` to your configuration class and then secure handler component methods with annotations, such as `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")`

This is how I managed to get this working with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4, but again this may depend on what kind of request handling you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue when using Spring Security with WebFlux. The workaround is posted here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16144