# Unable to resolve view exception with Spring Boot WebFlux when deploying as WAR

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

Facing below exception while deploying Spring WebFlux application as war file in tomcat.Extended with  AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherHandlerInitializer and implemented getConfigClasses method as below.

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestSpringApplication extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherHandlerInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
            WebConfig.class
        };
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class TestSpringController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public Mono<String> hello(Model model){

         return Mono.just("account");
    }
}
```

Note : account.html is placed under resources/templates

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'account'.
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$3(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:276) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107) [reactor-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot does not currently support WebFlux applications deployed as WAR.

You're here mixing the recommended setup by Spring Framework (see [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-reactive-spring-web) and especially the note that points to `AbstractServletHttpHandlerAdapterInitializer`) - and the WAR setup for Spring Boot MVC applications.

If you'd like to run a Spring Boot WebFlux app, please consider the executable JAR deployment model.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.I see there is bug in AbstractServletHttpHandlerAdapterInitializer in 5.0.1 version and I was trying workaroud suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325632/how-to-activate-spring-security-in-a-webflux-war-application but could not get it to work

Comment: that other question is only considering Spring Framework. Here you're trying to use Spring Boot features, which is a different use case.

Answer (score 11):

Use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` annotation of `TestSpringController` class

Alternatively, you can add the `@ResponseBody` annotations to controller methods annotated with `@Controller` which return a response body.

Comment: You should improve your response with information on @ResponseBody

Comment: Hi! Please add some explanation to your answer. Right now, it is currently being marked as low quality by review due to length and content and is at risk of being deleted by the system. Thanks!